# Difference between unsuited and unsuitable

Tags: differences

Can you use both words as synonyms? Or only in some cases? Or do they have completely different meanings?

Comment: According to online cambridge dictionary, both [unsuited](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unsuited) and [unsuitable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unsuitable) are adjectives. **Usage:** ***unsuited:*** `Liberman realized Kurt was unsuited to office life, but offered him a contract anyway.` ***unsuitable:*** `The software blocks material that is unsuitable for children.`

Comment: @Sandeep Presumably Liberman is ill-suited to office life because he always comes in unsuited, wearing jeans and a t-shirt …

Comment: I'd say if John is *unsuitable* for the job, that probably means it's an issue for his *employers* that he's not the right man for the job. But if he's *unsuited* to it, that's more likely to mean *John himself* isn't comfortable in the job (and therefore probably doesn't perform well in that position, but that's just a further inference).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNSUITED:

```
          (1) Not suited to a given purpose
```

UNSUITABLE:

> ```
>         (1) Not suited to a given purpose.
>
>         (2) Not suited to circumstances.
> ```

Unsuited and Unsuitable are SYNONYMS only in the context of (1) as mentioned in

http://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/unsuited

http://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/unsuitable

USAGE AS ADJECTIVES:

(1) Unsuited to/for

unsuited (to/for something) unsuited (to do something) not having the right or necessary qualities for something

- He is unsuited to academic work.
- She was totally unsuited for the job.

if two people are unsuited to each other they do not have the same interests, etc. and are therefore not likely to make a good couple

(2) Unsuitable for

- These shoes are unsuitable for walking
- The man is unsuitable for the post

CLEAR EXAMPLE:

You can say:

He is ***unsuitable*** for the post

He is ***unsuited*** for the post

You can say:

The film is ***unsuitable*** for children

You can't say:

The film is ***unsuited*** for children

DETAILED USAGE WITH EXAMPLES: Please refer below:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuited

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuitable

Hope that helps :-D